# Drupal 7 - views blocks not displaying page field content

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have a page where a view is creating a block which loads a field.

Other blocks loaded into the region are showing up just fine but that particular one will not show.  It is not because the field is empty or otherwise, I can creae labels and tables and empty conditions etc that do not get picked up at all

Is there something that has to be done to template files or otherwise to enable blocks created by views?

Comment: does ur block use a contextual filter?

Answer (score 0):

A block created by view shows up as any other view, unless you have permission control for the block at views level or at block level.

Permission at views

[image]

Permission at block

1. Visibility settings - By various ways block visibility can be controlled, ensure you have appropriate configurations for this.

[image]

2. Region Settings - Ensure you are putting the block in the region of right theme you are expecting the block to see.

Few things to debug.

- Login with super admin(user id 1) see if you can see the block, if yes it will ensure you have permission issues.